# Why isn't a class converted automatically in DataGrid when implicit conversion exists?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, implicit-conversion

I have a class `MyClass` with one property: `MyProperty` of type `MyPropertyClass`. `MyPropertyClass` has `implicit operator` for converting from `string`.

Now I want to bind to that property from a `DataGridTextColumn` in a **two-way**, but it doesn't work. In my opinion, it should automatically convert from `string` to `MyPropertyClass` and also back (using `ToString` method).

Error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to
>   perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'Test.MyPropertyClass' and
>   'System.String'. Consider using Converter property of Binding.
>   BindingExpression:Path=MyProperty; DataItem='MyClass'
>   (HashCode=22558296); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Text' (type 'String')

I know that I could define a `Converter` like the error description above states. But doing this is redundant as I would only use the `implicit conversion` from `string` to `MyPropertyClass` and the `ToString` method anyway.

Code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyPropertyClass MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class MyPropertyClass
{
    private string value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyPropertyClass(string s)
    {
        MyPropertyClass mc = new MyPropertyClass();
        mc.value = s;
        return mc;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List,Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="My Property" Binding="{Binding MyProperty,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a [TypeConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx).

1. [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/628879/Creating-a-custom-TypeConverter-Part-Getting-sta)
2. [Wpf2000things](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/type-converters/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I still think that writing these converters is redundant. I mean: I'm going to use `implicit conversion` and `ToString` method anyway. Why can't it do that automatically by itself?